# Load magento model that doesn't exist

Tags: php, magento

I'm in the process of converting the data from an old website to a new website.  I'm creating and populating customers inside a class that extends `Mage_Shell_Abstract`.

I want to load a customer if they already exist, or create them if they don't:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail('none@gmail.com');
$customer->setFirstName('John');
$customer->setLastName('Smith');
$customer->save();
```

Will this code cause any errors if no customer already exists with this email?

Comment: Define "will this code cause any errors". Surely it's easy to test this and refine if necessary :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure exactly what's meant by "magento model that doesn't exist", but if you're referring to the `customer/customer` model, it should work.

If you are within the `run()` method, then `Mage::app()` has already run within the `__construct()` method of `Mage_Shell_Abstract`, so you'll have access to all of the models and other magento features from within that context.

So `getCustomerByEmail()` will work just like it does normally, as well as all the other methods on that model or any other.

You should be able to do:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail('none@gmail.com');
if (!$customer->getId()) {
    // Create customer
}
```

Comment: I am calling my code from inside run().  It seems that magento returns an empty customer if it can't match by the email address.  I edited my question; do you see any potential errors with how I'm updating/creating customers?

Comment: I don't think that loadByEmail() does a setEmail() on the $customer, so you may need to throw that in.  But are you getting any exception currently?

Comment: The problem I missed was `$customer->getId()` returned a different value after calling `save()` depending on if the customer already existed or not.